# Issues running Google App Engine examples locally on Mac

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty, google-cloud-platform

I've tried to run a number of the Java Google App Engine examples locally on my MacBook (Sierra 10.12.6). I've followed the official guides and have successfully installed the gcloud toolkit and the app engine component:

```
gcloud components list 

│ Installed     │ BigQuery Command Line Tool │ bq                 
│ Installed     │ Cloud SDK Core Libraries │ core                    
│ Installed     │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool │ gsutil                   
│ Installed     │ gcloud app Java Extensions │ app-engine-java    
│ Installed     │ gcloud app Python Extensions │ app-engine-python
```

Any examples I have tried do build and run as expected. However, when I access the localhost endpoint I just get the error

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

This is also the case using 127.0.0.1:8080

I've tried building and running from the Eclipse plugin and from CLI using maven but have the same issue with both. In the maven case there are no warnings or errors:

```
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
...
[INFO] INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
```

I have also disabled antivirus in case that was blocking anything.

---

As an update, in the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java examples, I see the above issue with the examples for the standard java8 app engine:

```
getting-started-java/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld
```

However, when I run the servlet example I do get data on the localhost endpoint:

```
getting-started-java/helloworld-servlet
```

Comment: I wonder if there is some exception that is being suppressed. Before running in Eclipse, open the _Breakpoints_ view, and add a Java exception breakpoint on _Throwable_, and mark it to _include all subclasses_.

Comment: Looking at your log some more, it looks like you're using the older `com.google.appengine` plugin for Maven, and not the newer `com.google.cloud.tools.appengine` plugin as the latter prefixes the output lines with `GCLOUD:`.  Could you please post your entire Maven console log from the `mvn appengine:run`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first suggestion of using the Eclipse plugin with breakpoints for all Throwables and interestingly get a ClassNotFoundEception "com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain"

Comment: After a complete restart I also tried the `getting-started-java/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld` example again and do now seem to be able to see output on 127.0.0.1:8080 so that's a start. Maybe there are a couple issues going on :)